# Using Serilog with appsettings.json in C# Library - .NET Core Standard

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I am creating a library that wraps around Serilog and I wanted to know if I can use an `appsettings.json`?

I have installed `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.json` and put this code in the constructor of a `Logging.cs` class:

```
public class Logger
{
    private StringWriter messages { get; set; }
    private Serilog.Core.Logger logger {get; set;}

    public Logger()
    {
        messages = new StringWriter();

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.TextWriter(messages)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

I have also placed this in the `csproj` but I'm not sure if its needed:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Unless I'm wrong, I have no way to run this library to debug the constructor code to see if its successfully retrieving my `appsettings.json` configuration, hence the question.

Another question is can I use both `appsettings.json` configuration and code configuration like I have above `LoggerConfiguration()`?  The reason for this is that I want to use the `.WriteTo.TextWriter()` that needs a `StringWriter` variable that needs to be accessed somewhere else in the library.

Comment: In your solution, you can add console project to test. But generally, it's the main project that initialize the configuration and inject in library service.

Comment: You can combine `appsettings.json` and code configuration. I've done it few times and had no problems with it.

Comment: Thank you both, I've added a main console project to my solution and instantiated a new `Logger` and debugged the `configuration` variable from the `Logger.cs` class and it is retrieving my `appsettings.json` as it should :-)  I'm still wondering if the `xml` i put in the `csproj` is needed though?